# q promise resolved before completed?

Tags: angularjs, q

I think I may be missing something fundamental about how a promise works, because I never seem to be getting the result I expect, so hoping someone can correct my thinking.

In this case, it is a relatively easy call. I have a angular factory that among other things gets some data from the API (which makes a call to mongodb).
As there is a $http request (which is asynchronous), I wrapped the http call in a $q function which should return a `resolve` if successful and a `reject` if an error.

```
factory.loadLayout = function (layoutName) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        $http.get('/api/getlayout/'+layoutName)
            .success(function (data) {
                layout = data;
                console.log("Got " + layout.name);
                resolve('OK');
            })
            .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
               reject(new Error( status));
            });


    });
}
```

I then have another function which is dependent on the data collected in the first function, called getButtonId, but as far as I can tell, and even though it is wrapped in the `.then`, it seems like it is called before the promise is resolved.

```
var promise = padArea.loadLayout(layoutName);
    promise.then(padArea.getButtonId('A0'));
```

So what am I missing?

== UPDATE == 
So trying the same thing using q.defer

```
factory.loadLayout = function (layoutName) {
    var defer = $q.defer()
        $http.get('/api/getlayout/'+layoutName)
            .success(function (data) {
                layout = data;
                console.log("Got " + layout.name);
                defer.resolve('OK');
            })
            .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
               defer.reject(new Error( status));
            });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Still not working as I expect, and the function inside .then is still called before http have completed.

== UPDATE 2 ==
OK, so got it working (if I just call the function in the factory inside the .then, it calls it directly, however, if I wrap it in a function as below, it all of a sudden works. Can anyone explain why though, because to me it seems like wrapping the call to a function inside a function should make no difference from just calling the function.

```
padArea.loadLayout(layoutName).then(function(result){
    padArea.getButtonId('A0')
});
```

Strangely enough, as long as I wrap the second call in ( the one inside the .then ) my original code works as well.

Comment: `$q` returns a resolved promise already.

Comment: So how do I get it to wait until it is suppose to resolve the promise.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this: http://plnkr.co/edit/rlvnuTvm1b0C1fh0Oabk?p=preview *but* `$http` returns a promise anyway, so you can just remove all of the `$q` functionality and return the `$http.get` call instead and the functionality should be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$http` promise:

```
factory.loadLayout = function (layoutName) {
  return $http.get('/api/getlayout/'+layoutName)
        .success(function (data) {
            layout = data;
            console.log("Got " + layout.name);
            resolve('OK');
        })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
           reject(new Error( status));
        });
}
```

And then to use it...

`factory.loadLayout(param).then(function (response) { ... });`

**OR**

I see what you are trying to do.  Instead create a deffered from `$q`

```
factory.loadLayout = function (layoutName) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/getlayout/'+layoutName)
        .success(function (data) {
            layout = data;
            console.log("Got " + layout.name);
            defer.resolve('OK');
        })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
           defer.reject(new Error( status));
        });
  return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions seems to work. the $q.defer does not throw any errors, but the function within the .then statement still runs before the http.get gets called (tried to use $http with resolve and reject, just got that these where undefined. (have updated the example above).

Comment: The second one worked, as long as it was wrapped in a function.

Comment: You have to wrap it in a function because `.then` expects a function as its parameter.  Your other options is `.then(padArea.getButtonId.bind(padArea, 'A0'))`

Comment: Thank you very much Erik for taking the time to answer my first and second question:)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use $q.defer():

```
deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get('/api/getlayout/'+layoutName)
    .success(function (data) {
        layout = data;
        deferred.resolve("OK");
    })
    .error(function (data,status,headers,config){
        deferred.reject(new Error(status));
    })

return deferred.promise;
```

This can be a little more general if you're not just doing an http request, and lets you control the return.